# Par rate of Interest Rate Swap

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap

I'm interested in deriving the par rate of an interest rate swap priced under the single curve framework. Let's follow the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest_rate_swap) for the sake of notation simplicity.

The present value of the fixed leg can be calculated as
$$PV_{fixed} = NR\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}d_i x_i,$$
where $N$ is the notional, $R$ is the fixed rate, $n_1$ is the number of payments of the fixed leg, $d_1$ is the decimalised day count fraction of the accrual in the $i$'th period and $x_i$ is the corresponding discounting factor.

Similarly the present value of the floating leg is given by
$$PV_{float} = N\sum_{j=1}^{n_2}r_j d_j x_j,$$
where $n_2$ is the number of payments of the floating leg and $r_j$ are the forecasting (forward) rates.

In order to find the par rate we set $PV_{fixed} - PV_{float} = 0$ and solve for $R$, the resulting expression is
$$R = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n_2} r_j d_j x_j}{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} d_i x_i}.$$

However, Wikipedia claims that under the single curve framework this expression can be simplified further to
$$R = \frac{x_0 - x_{n_2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} d_i x_i}$$

The above expression isn't obvious to me. How do we conclude that $\sum_{j=1}^{n_2} r_j d_j x_j = x_0 - x_{n_2}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the fact that, under the single-curve framework, the projected rate $r_j$ is found via:

$$r_j = \frac{\frac{x_{j-1}}{x_j} - 1}{d_j}$$

If you plug in this expression for $r_j$ in the summation then all terms will cancel out except for $x_0$ and $x_{n_2}$.